# How to change button's image when tapped using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm beginner at Swift. I want to change the button's image after retrieving it from Firebase Realtime Database and when I tap. I'm using a custom class named `CustomClass` and I have tried to set the image if the boolean value in database is true and set it to nil if the value is false.

My issues:

- I can't change the image after retrieving data from Firebase.
- I can change it the first time when I tap, but second time I can't change it.

In cellForRowAt method,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = InfoTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    let keyword = cell.nameLabel.text
    var reference: DatabaseReference!
    cell.buttonAction = { sender in

        if  (sender as AnyObject).imageView?.image != nil{
            cell.prayButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
            reference = Database.database().reference().child("check" ).child(keyword!).child("prayCheck")
                   reference.setValue(false)
        } else{
                    let image = UIImage(named: "check")
            cell.prayButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                        reference = Database.database().reference().child("check").child(keyword!).child("prayCheck")
                        reference.setValue(true)
        }

    }
    cell.moneyButtonAction = { sender in


        if  (sender as AnyObject).imageView?.image != nil {
            cell.moneyButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
                   reference = Database.database().reference().child("check").child(keyword!).child("moneyCheck")
                   reference.setValue(false)
        } else {
                   let image = UIImage(named: "check")
            cell.moneyButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                    reference = Database.database().reference().child("check").child(keyword!).child("moneyCheck")
                   reference.setValue(true)
        }

    }
    cell.atentionButtonAction = { sender in

        if (sender as AnyObject).imageView?.image != nil {
            cell.alartButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
                   reference = Database.database().reference().child("check").child(keyword!).child("atentionCheck")
                   reference.setValue(false)
        } else {
                    let image = UIImage(named: "check")
            cell.alartButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                    reference = Database.database().reference().child("check").child(keyword!).child("atentionCheck")
                    reference.setValue(true)
               }
    }



    return cell

   }
```

In custom class,

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet  weak var bookingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet  weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var applyDateLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var nameIcon: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var applyIcon: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bookinfIcon: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var prayImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var receiveMoneyImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var atentionImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var prayButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var moneyButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var alartButton: UIButton!

    var pathKey: String!
    var reference: DatabaseReference!
    var buttonAction: ((Any) -> Void)?
    var moneyButtonAction: ((Any) -> Void)?
    var atentionButtonAction:((Any) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any){

    self.buttonAction?(sender)

    }

    @IBAction func moneyButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.moneyButtonAction?(sender)
    }


    @IBAction func atentionButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.atentionButtonAction?(sender)
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be that reference - lost

Try to make some refactoring

```
cell.buttonAction = { sender in
     configureAction(type: .moneyCheck)
}
```

And replace this code into function with 1 Parameter

**moneyCheck**/**atentionCheck**/**prayCheck**

```
func configureAction(type: FieldTypeEnum) {
 let isNotNull = (sender as AnyObject).imageView?.image != nil
        reference.setValue(isNotNull)
        reference = Database.database().reference().child("check").child(keyword!).child("prayCheck")
        let image: UIImage? = isNotNil ? UIImage(named: "check") : nil
        cell.prayButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
}
```

Better if you will put into Enum

Comment: Thank you for answer. In your func, there is ```reference.setValue(isNotNull)``` above ```reference = Database.database().....```. Is it right?